# Python and Snowflake rollback is not executed on specific condition within an iteration of a loop

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rollback

I am connecting into Snowflake cloud using the following:

```
try:
    conn = snowCtx.connect(
        user=snowflake_user,
        password=password,
        account=account,
        database=database,
        schema=schema,
        warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
        role='SYSADMIN',
        autocommit = False
    )
    conn.autocommit = False


except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, snowCtx.connection.errors.Error) as e:
    print("******* Main error on connection: *******\n"+ str(e))
    print("******* Main error on connection: *******\n"+ str(e), file=logfile)
    conn.rollback()
```

**And I am looping into an array, and calling some functions. What I need is to rollback everything happened within a specific loop if an error occured**

Here is the loop script:

```
for main_survey_id in survey_ids_list:

    print('--- Starting with Data related to the main data.csv survey: '+main_survey+' ---\n')
    print('--- Starting with Data related to the main data.csv survey: '+main_survey+' ---\n', file=logfile)
    # Other variables sent with the functions:
    ...
    data['SURVEY_ID'] = main_survey_id
    add_dataframe = add_dataframe_as_table(conn, cursor, data, survey_new_title)
    nested_foreign_key = add_foreign_key(conn, cursor, main_survey, survey_new_title, '_parent_index', '_index')
    add_columns = add_survey_columns(conn, cursor, a, survey_new_title, data, main_survey_id)
    if((add_columns == True) and (nested_foreign_key==True) and (add_dataframe)==True):
        new_row = {'ONA Survey ID': ona_survey_id, 'Snowflake Survey ID': next_val, 
                                   'Survey Title': survey_new_title, 'Upload Status': 'SUCCESS', 'ONA id exists': 'True', 
                                   'Survey Type': 'Nested Table',
                                   'Survey title exists?': 'False', 
                                   'Survey have nested values': have_nested, 'Table Added': 'True', 
                                   'Primary Key Added': '', 'Foreign Key Added': nested_foreign_key,
                                   'Number of rows of table': len(data), 'Comments': 'Success: Nested table added to Snowflake'}
        log_frame = log_frame.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

        conn.commit()
    else:
        conn.rollback()
```

You can see here if all called functions returned `True`, then I need to commit the changes happened on the database, else `rollback()` and proceed into the next iteration.

Here is a function script as well:

```
def add_foreign_key(conn, cursor, reference_table_name, child_table_name, child_table_key_name, reference_table_key_name):
    print('Add_Foreign_Key')
    try:
        print('--- Adding a foreign key between the child table: '+child_table_name+ ' and the reference table: '+reference_table_name+' with foreign key as: '+child_table_key_name+' ---\n')
        print('--- Adding a foreign key between the child table: '+child_table_name+ ' and the reference table: '+reference_table_name+' with foreign key as: '+child_table_key_name+' ---\n', file=logfile
             )
        child_table = "\""+database+"\".\""+schema+"\".\""+child_table_name+"\""
        reference_table_name = "\""+database+"\".\""+schema+"\".\""+reference_table_name+"\""
        print(child_table)
        query = """ALTER TABLE {0} ADD FOREIGN KEY ({1}) REFERENCES {2}({3})"""\
            .format(child_table.replace('\'', '\'\''), child_table_key_name, reference_table_name.replace('\'', '\'\''), reference_table_key_name)
        print("Foreign Key Query: "+query+"\n")
        print("Foreign Key Query: "+query+"\n", file=logfile)
        if(cursor.execute(query)):
            print("--- "+child_table+ " FOREIGN KEY added successfully"+" ---\n")
            print("--- "+child_table+ " FOREIGN KEY added successfully"+" ---\n", file=logfile)
            # conn.commit()
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, snowCtx.connection.errors.Error) as e:
        print("******* Error when adding foreign key: "+ str(e)+" *******\n")
        print("******* Error when adding foreign key: "+ str(e)+" *******\n", file=logfile)
        return False
```

The rollback() is not working. I am receiving SQL Error at the console like following, but no rollback is being done.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake DDL statements implicitly COMMIT open transactions, so you might consider approaching this differently, perhaps cloning the objects before the process and then if anything fails along the way you can perform a swap operation in your exception clause.

Relevant doc links:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#label-transactions-ddl

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html